# Visa issuance without having a passport

Tags: visas, new-zealand

My cousin told me that New Zealand issued him a visa. Is it possible to obtain a visa from there if you don't have a passport?

Answer (score 1):

Even with the NZ eVisa system, the answer to the OP's question is "no."

Applying for an eVisa requires that the applicant possess a valid passport. Like other online visa systems, the visa application is submitted online and requires the applicant to upload a photo of the applicant's passport information and signature pages. If granted, the visa is sent to the applicant by email, and usually must be printed and hand-carried at entry to the visa-granting country.

More information on NZ entry is available on [this travel.stackexchange.com page.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101851/passport-validity-for-new-zealand-visa-waiver?rq=1)