# Passport validity for New Zealand Visa Waiver

Tags: visas, new-zealand

Is there an official source stating how much time more my passport needs to be valid after I return from my trip to New Zealand?

Or, since it allows me up to 6 months, it means that my passports needs to be valid AFTER that period, even if I'm staying only for a few weeks? I never visited New Zealand before.

Comment: What nationality are you? I'm assuming British, since only a British passport holder is eligible for a 6 month visa waiver, but can you confirm?

Comment: Brazil, it's 3 months under Visa Waiver program. Planning to travel in January, but my passport expires in May. If it is 6 months, I can't make it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(As the OP has expressed concern about no visa-waiver specific guidance and wanting advice specifically from the Immigration New Zealand website, I have edited my question to make this exceptionally clear)

The [August 2017 Visitor Visa Guide INZ 1018](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/documents/forms-and-guides/inz1018.pdf) has this to say on page 3, as part of the "Visa-Waiver visitors" section (starting on page 2):

> If you are in one of these groups, you are a ‘visawaiver
>   visitor’, and you do not need a visitor visa
>   to travel to New Zealand. You need to apply for
>   a visitor visa, but you will do this by completing
>   an arrival card on the aircraft/ship on your way
>   to New Zealand. You must also:
>
> - hold a valid ticket out of New Zealand to a
>     country you have the right of entry to
> - have enough money to support yourself during
>     your stay
> - ***hold a passport valid for three months beyond
>     the date you are leaving New Zealand.***

Emphasis my own.

This is backed up in general by other New Zealand government websites giving the same advice across the board.

According to the official New Zealand tourism website, your passport has to be valid for 3 months after your *departure* date:

> When you arrive, you’ll need to ensure your passport is valid for at least three months beyond your intended departure date, and if required, have a valid New Zealand visa.

http://www.newzealand.com/int/visas-and-immigration/

This is supported by the NZ Customs website:

> To enter the country you must have a passport and it must be valid for at least three months past the date that you intend to leave New Zealand.

http://www.customs.govt.nz/inprivate/traveltonz/immigration/pages/default.aspx

On the main NZ gov site:

> a passport that's valid for at least 3 months after the date you plan to leave NZ

https://www.govt.nz/browse/immigration-and-visas/applying-for-a-visitors-visa/how-to-apply-for-a-visitors-visa/

Comment: Despite both websites being from government, none of them are from the agency that regulates immigration, so not the most accurate information. I couldn't find anything in www.immigration.govt.nz stating that, I was hoping I missed this page in their website.

Comment: @RafaelKassner how's that?

Comment: your edit says about Visitor Visa, not Visa Waiver, but I guess it's safe to assume it will be the same requirement.

Comment: @RafaelKassner the quote from page 3 of the August 2017 guide refers to visa waiver visitors. Did you not read it?

Comment: @RafaelKassner edited to make it completely clear

Comment: haven't before, wasn't opening. Now I see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RafaelKassner glad to be of help :)